# IF condition with && operator, true all, final result FALSE, with AND keyword it is good

Tags: ruby

I have that if condition that both sides are resulting true when I inspect debugging each side separated, when I inspect both together with the `&&` operator, it results `false`.

All those variables and constants are STRINGS, no numbers here.

```
[Budget::STATUS_ACCEPTED[:value], Budget::STATUS_WAITING_PAYMENT[:value]].include? status_was && status == Budget::STATUS_WAITING_PRODUCTION[:value]
```

The same code using `and` keyword results `true`. Any idea why this is resulting `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code translates into

```
[Budget::STATUS_ACCEPTED[:value], Budget::STATUS_WAITING_PAYMENT[:value]].include? (status_was && status == Budget::STATUS_WAITING_PRODUCTION[:value])
```

which would probably always return `false` because `status_was && status == Budget::STATUS_WAITING_PRODUCTION[:value]` will always return `false`.

You should use parenthesis in this case. Hint: precedence.

```
[Budget::STATUS_ACCEPTED[:value], Budget::STATUS_WAITING_PAYMENT[:value]].include?(status_was) &&
  status == Budget::STATUS_WAITING_PRODUCTION[:value]
```

Comment: Oh god, so elementary. I was crazy about that because using AND keyword it works and that precedence is not the same...

Comment: @RamondePaulaMarques yea, `&&` and `and` are different. I prefer using `()` to avoid potential confusion for interpreter and myself reading code later :)